# Circular Dependancy Caused by dagger-hilt

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt, multi-module

i am following multi module architecture with MVVM clean arch and i am beginner for dagger-hilt. so i have 2 modules data and domain which causing circular dependancy i dont what causing this error i am beginner to a dagger hilt i apologize if i done anything stupid

```
Error:
* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:AppLockFeature:data:compileDebugAidl
\--- :AppLockFeature:domain:compileDebugAidl
     \--- :AppLockFeature:data:compileDebugAidl (*)



//domain module
interface AppLockRepo {
    fun getInstalledApps(): Flow<List<ApplicationInfo>>
}
```

```
// data module
class AppLockRepoImpl (val packageManager: PackageManager): AppLockRepo {
    override fun getInstalledApps(): Flow<List<ApplicationInfo>> {
        return flow {
            packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//domain module
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object AppLockDomainModule {

    @ViewModelScoped
    @Singleton
    fun provideUseCases( repo: AppLockRepo): AppLockUseCases {
        return AppLockUseCases(
            GetInstalledApps(repo)
        )
    }
}
```

```
//domain module
class GetInstalledApps (
    val repo: AppLockRepo
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<List<ApplicationInfo>>{
        return repo.getInstalledApps()
    }
}
```

```
data class AppLockUseCases(
      val getInstalledApps: GetInstalledApps
)
```

```
// data module
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppLockDataModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAppList(app:Application): PackageManager {
        return app.packageManager
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAppLockRepo(packageManager: PackageManager): AppLockRepo {
        return AppLockRepoImpl(packageManager)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, but first you should read document carefully !

```
//domain module
interface AppLockRepo {
    fun getInstalledApps(): Flow<List<ApplicationInfo>>
}

// data module
class AppLockRepoImpl @Inject constructor(val packageManager: PackageManager): AppLockRepo {
    override fun getInstalledApps(): Flow<List<ApplicationInfo>> {
        return flow {
            packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
        }
    }
}

//domain module
class GetInstalledApps @Inject constructor(
    val repo: AppLockRepo
) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<List<ApplicationInfo>>{
        return repo.getInstalledApps()
    }
}

data class AppLockUseCases @Inject constructor(
      val getInstalledApps: GetInstalledApps
)

// data module
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppLockDataModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAppList(app:Application): PackageManager {
        return app.packageManager
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface CompressionModule {

    @Binds
    fun provideAppLockRepo(impl: AppLockRepoImpl): AppLockRepo
}
```